# How does innoDB aquire locks for multiple rows and subqueries?

Tags: mysql, locking, deadlock

We have a deadlock situation when our server processes two specific requests 1 and 2.

The database has the tables `order_item` and `product`. The `order_item` has a foreign key constraint on `product`.

(1) Starts a manual SQL transaction and inserts multiple `order_items`. Therefore this transaction requests multiple locks on individual `product` PRIMARY indices sequentially.

```
INSERT INTO order_item (...) VALUES (...)
INSERT INTO order_item (...) VALUES (...)
...
```

(2) Is a single big UPDATE statement, that updates most `product`s but also scans `order_item`s and some other tables.

```
UPDATE product
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ... FROM order_item ... INNER JOIN product ...)
...
```

Now we have a deadlock situation. `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` suggests that **both** transactions hold locks on `product` and await more locks, even though (2) is actually a single SQL statement.

> *** (1) TRANSACTION:
> TRANSACTION 39503904, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
> mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
> LOCK WAIT 52 lock struct(s), heap size 8400, 45 row lock(s), undo log entries 22
> MySQL thread id 3651, OS thread handle 123145451790336, query id 1271704 localhost root update
> INSERT INTO `order_item` ...
> *** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
> RECORD LOCKS space id 317598 page no 30 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `product` trx id 39503904 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
> *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
> RECORD LOCKS space id 317598 page no 29 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `product` trx id 39503904 lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting\

> *** (2) TRANSACTION:
> TRANSACTION 39503901, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
> mysql tables in use 4, locked 4
> LOCK WAIT 495 lock struct(s), heap size 73936, 21867 row lock(s), undo log entries 184
> MySQL thread id 3647, OS thread handle 123145450577920, query id 1271692 localhost root
> UPDATE `product` ...
> *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
> RECORD LOCKS space id 317598 page no 29 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `product` trx id 39503901 lock_mode X
> *** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
> RECORD LOCKS space id 317598 page no 30 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `product` trx id 39503901 lock_mode X waiting\

So as I understand it, the deadlock dump says that transaction (2) which is a single UPDATE statement also tries to aquire locks **sequentially** even though it is a single statement. Is that how locks for multiple rows are requested internally? Is it because of the sub queries(joins)? I could not find this detail in the documentation. We are using MySQL 8.0.19.